# LIMBO White Screen after upgrading to 22.10

Tags: upgrade, games, steam, 22.10, white-screen

After upgrading to Ubuntu 22.10, I cannot play anymore to LIMBO on Steam (natively supported). In 22.04 everything was working perfectly.

I can see the Loading Screen
[image]

But then it turns to a White Screen. I can hear sound but cannot see anything.
[image]

Shall I install any third party software? Limbo is natively supported on Linux.

Note: I had to fix audio/sound after upgrading from previous Ubuntu version as well.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is a graphics driver update that broke the build. Playdead is working on it and they hope to release a fix soon.

**Update**:
Playdead released an update, make sure you also have the latest stable version of Mesa driver. After updating to Mesa 23.0.0 I'm able to play again this great game!

Limbo issue: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa/-/issues/7976

Ubuntu: https://itsfoss.com/install-mesa-ubuntu/